# Detach debugger(unknown) from process?

Tags: debugging, winapi, reverse-engineering

I am trying to attach debugger(windbg,ollydbg) to running process but there's an error saying Debugger is already attached then how can i detach that unknown debugger from that process?
Process includes multi thread, one thread can be attached to debugger and other can't.

Answer (score 4):

The process might be spawning a second process which attaches to the first process for debugging using `DebugActiveProcess()` in order to prevent people from debugging the first process. Keep in mind that a process cannot debug itself using this method, so a second process must be spawned to do this.

Things you could try:

- Use any sort of process monitor or even task manager to figure out what process the first process spawns
- Inject code into the second process to call `DebugActiveProcessStop()` to detach it from the first process
- Hook `DebugActiveProcess()` (`kernel32.DebugActiveProcess`, `ntdll.ZwDebugActiveProcess`, or in kernelmode) and redirect it to attach to a different dummy process
- Kill the second process
- Prevent the second process from getting a handle to the first process with the needed permissions - `DebugActiveProcess()` will then fail
- Use alternative debugging methods (Cheat engine with VEH debugging for example) that don't use the normal debugging API's and therefore bypass this problem

Comment: Thanks for reply.@higaki It seems that you know lot's in debugging.can you please send me your email address to asdqwer258@gmail.com? so i can directly contact you for my problems.Thanks.

Comment: You say that process cannot debug it self but i see in task manager that both process are of same name. I am little bit confused about that.

Comment: And both process start from same exe [concluded from api monitor].

Comment: Processes can have the same name, start from the same exe, and still do different things. The second process may be started with different commandline arguments, or it may check to see if a process with the same name is already running, or it might use some other check to know if a copy of itself is already running (for example, using CreateMutex). Then when the second process detects that there is already the first process running, it can do something different (such as attach to the first process).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried following code from your suggestion.........#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
 long d;
 bool i;
 HANDLE handle= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, 1992);
 cout<<handle;
 i=DebugActiveProcessStop(1992);
 d=GetLastError();
 cout<<endl<<d<<endl<<i; 
 return 0; 
}    where 1992 is process id and output was 0x28,5,0 after execution of   above code i'm not able to attach that process(pid..1992).

Comment: I have also tried similar code for function DebugBreakProcess() but it's also not working...........Debugee information [All in one keylogger,self modifying ,seems to having armadillo protection ]

Comment: You are getting an Access Denied error because you are not calling DebugActiveProcessStop() from the same thread (and the same process of course) that DebugActiveProcess() was called from. You will need to inject your code into the second process, find the thread that called DebugActiveProcess(), and then redirect it to execute your code (google "dll injection" and "api hooking" if you're unfamiliar with those). That's a difficult way to do it though, so you may want to try one of the other methods first.